# How I can Create log for post deployment script in dacpac?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools, database-project, dacpac

I am using the SQL server Database Project. To deploy .dacpac file I am using the SqlPackage.exe with command line arguments.

Using Action: DriftReport,  I am able to create the log (Added/update/Modified) of objects. But Still I am not able to create the log for post deployment script (operation like insert, update, etc).

Is there any way to create reports for successful and failures data insertion.

Comment: Have you tried piping the output to a file? That will give you something. However, to truly catch everything, you'll want to code it in by hand.

Comment: I have tried to save command line output which will show after execute command to publish. If any post deployment script failed then it will show on console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I have done to achieve this is about same as Peter's comment. I got a batch file something as follow

```
sqlpackage.exe /a:publish /tcs:"the connection string" /sf:".\package.dacpac"  >"%1" 2>"%2"
FOR %%A IN ("%2") DO SET FileSize=%%~zA
if %FileSize% gtr 0 start notepad "%2"
```

Then I would run the batch as:

```
thebatch.bat result.txt error_result.text
```

The idea was redirect the output of this console command into file "result.txt"(by using " >") and redirect the error message to "error_result.text"(by using " 2>"), and then to rely on %~z in batch file to get a file size and open the file only if something went wrong.

Comment: Simon has it right, the thing to note is ">" and "2>" as you need to redirect both stdout and stderr to get all messages.